# Pacman: Stop him from moving one direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, pacman

I'm making a pacman game. If you've ever played it you'll know that when pacman is moving a certain direction through a maze, if he moves towards a wall nothing happens. He just keeps going. What would be a a good way of doing this given my current code?

So here's the code.

```
this.move = function(key){ 

   var Rblocked = false;
   var Bblocked = false;               

  clearInterval(timer);

  timer = window.setInterval(function(){

//key is event switch   
    switch (key) {      
      case 39:
          for (var butt39 in blockArrayLeft){
        if ($('#pacMan').position().left == blockArrayLeft[butt39].position().left && $('#pacMan').position().top == blockArrayLeft[butt39].position().top){

          Rblocked = true;
          pacMan.move(this.direction);

        }
          }

        if (!Rblocked){

         this.direction = 39;
      pacMan.rightMove();
        }
      break;
    case 40:
         for (var butt40 in blockArrayTop){
        if ($('#pacMan').position().left == blockArrayTop[butt40].position().left && $('#pacMan').position().top == blockArrayTop[butt40].position().top){

          Bblocked = true;
          pacMan.move(this.direction);
        }
          }
        if (!Bblocked){

       this.direction = 40;   
      pacMan.bottomMove();
        }
      break;
      default:
        clearInterval(timer);

        break;
        }     

}
};
}
```

Pressing a key causes pacMan to move one direction continuously. I have a setInterval that makes him move his length's space, every 100 seconds.

If he bumps into a wall and he moves towards it he is blocked. The setInterval only goes when the blocked variable is false.

But what would be a way to make him keep moving a direction if he goes right suddenly?

Comment: Conceptually, I think you'll want those Boolean variables to be generated during every single loop execution, rather than kept as globals. There is not a lot of useful data you can "remember" between loop states aside from Mr. Pac's position; you'd have to just re-check it anyway.

Comment: Can you post your code in a jsfiddle with html?